# setting the encoding of a System.Net.Mail.MailMessage body while getting text from xml using c#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, encoding

I'm trying to set the encoding of a `MailMessage` body so it is able to display german "umlauts" (ä, ö, ü). I get the message text from an xml file. The encoding of the xml is `iso-8859-1` and also is the `MailMessage` body.

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.From = new MailAddress(sFrom);
msg.To.Add(sTo);
msg.Subject = sSubject;
msg.Body = sBody;
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
msg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
```

The first line of xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```

I also tried `UTF8` and `Unicode` encoding, but that doesn't help neither. The body is still unable to display umlauts.

Is there anything special I have to notice or am I just using the wrong encoding?

**EDIT:** It's a Windows Forms application and I'm using .NET framework 4.5.2

**EDIT2:** I'm using `XmlSerializer` to get the xml data.

```
XmlSerializer xSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(App));

using (StreamReader srXml = new StreamReader(_sFileName))
{
    _oAppConfig = (App)xSerializer.Deserialize(srXml);
}
```

Note that `App` is a class I created for my own.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint after the msg.Body assignment and verified it displays the characters correctly at that point? My guess is it's corrupted while reading the XML because of wrong encoding. For example I tried reading a sample file with *File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/XMLFile1.xml"))* but only worked after I specified the encoding: *File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/XMLFile1.xml"), Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"))*

Comment: Well, the body string is wrong as you expected. It just puts some symbols like � instead of umlauts. I'm using `XmlSerializer` to get the xml data. I'll add this to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the Encoding while reading the file such as:

```
XmlSerializer xSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(App));

using (StreamReader srXml = new StreamReader(_sFileName, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")) )
{
    _oAppConfig = (App)xSerializer.Deserialize(srXml);
}
```